# Aggregation functions and pagination in corda

Tags: pagination, corda

Does corda support pagination with aggregate functions?

For example: I need to call vault for sum values grouped by some string
and in return get part of result e.g. first 10 values of 100, next 10 values of 100 etc.

As far as I know aggregate functions return results in "otherResult" field, so paging parameters don't apply with that.

How can corda deal with that use case?

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support pagination of results using aggregate functions (thanks for raising this so we can improve our documentation edge cases).
As an alternative you can write a custom query using native JDBC.
Use the `jdbcSession` API call from the ServiceHub to gain access to a JDBC session.

See the following example in our documentation:
https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/api-persistence.html?highlight=custom%20query#jdbc-session